# How to use cache feature in polymer 1.0 to save and reuse an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, caching, polymer, polymer-1.0

We have the luxury of platinum element platinum-sw-cache which enables to offline manage the data.

Basically, I am trying to create an element that displays most recently used list of items in my application and I think caching is the way to do it.

How can I use the element to save an array such that It can be used later.

I do not find any usable tutorial on this.

Comment: platinum-sw-cache can cache URLs of the your app. If the list is generated from an API endpoint, you could use SW to cache that URL (e.g. so a network request isn't made). If you want to cache the actual array itself, you'd have to use `<iron-localStorage>` or IDB to stash the result of the API call.

Comment: @ebidel thanks for your comment. I am using the below snippet , how can i edit the array to add new value?

Comment: `this.push("recentFood", newVal)` should do it.

Comment: When i try this, it throws an error in polymer.html like :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined polymer.html 1711

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```html
<dom-module id="recent-items">
 
 <template>
  <iron-localstorage name="my-app-storage"
    value="{{recentFood}}"
    on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefault"
  ></iron-localstorage>
 <template is ="dom-repeat" items={{recentFood}}>

<div class="horizontal layout">{{item}}</div>

</template> 

</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'recent-items',
    properties: {
      recentFood: {
        type: Array
      }
    },
    // initializes default if nothing has been stored
    initializeDefault: function() {
     
     var tempItems=new Array();
     
     tempItems[0]="Pizza";
     
     this.recentFood=tempItems.slice();

     
    },
     // use path set api to propagate changes to localstorage
    makeModifications: function() {

    }
    
  });
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: This works thank you. However i am not able to add a new value to the array. Can you help?

Comment: No idea, may be I am missing something. I will see